# How to convert hex-bytes String to uint8_t *array?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I have a String of hex-bytes in this form:
[image]

How can I convert these bytes to uint8_t *array?

It's an image for e-ink display and I want to show it with `void drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t w, int16_t h, uint16_t color);` from https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library/graphics-primitives .

I'm using ESP8266 and hex-bytes String is loaded from SPIFFS file.
Thanks.

I've tried:

```
File f = SPIFFS.open("/photo1.txt", "r");
      String input = f.readString();
      Serial.println(input);

      Serial.println("Converting to vector");
      std::vector<uint8_t> output;
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2) {
        char byte_digits[3] = { input[i], input[i + 1] };
        int value = strtoul(byte_digits, nullptr, 16);
        output.push_back(value);
      }

      Serial.println("Converting to uint8_t arr");
      uint8_t *img = output.data();
```

ESP gets restarted when reach Converting to vector:
[image]

Comment: Extract two characters at a time from the input string, convert to a byte, add to the container?

Comment: I've tried multiple ways, but ESP is restarting, so I think it runs out of memory. I don't know how to do this correctly :(

Comment: `for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2) { char byte_digits[3] = { input[i], input[i + 1] }; int value = strtoul(byte_digits, nullptr, 16); output.push_back(value); }`

Comment: Is this a C question where you mean with String a char* or char[] or is it a C++ question where you mean with String the C++ datatype ````std::string````? And what do you mean with array? Is it a C-Style uint8_t[] or a C++ std::array? This info is necessary to give the correct answer.

Comment: @ArminMontigny I'm not sure, as I'm not very experienced in C/C++, but I hope Arduino is C++.
I've posted code, what I've tried.

Comment: @ArminMontigny As you see in the edited question called "answer" , it's neither `std::string` nor `char*`, but an Arduino String object, and its `[ ]` operator.

Comment: Maybe it's connected with long-time work and soft watchdog stops it, but I don't know. It's tough :\

Answer (score 1):

Exception (29) is 'storeprohibitedcause'.

Try to change for condition into input.length() - 2.